# Converting pinyin with tones into chinese characters

Tags: pinyin, tones

Does anybody know how to convert pinyin with tone marks back into chinese characters.

I am using [www.branah.com/chinese-to-pinyin](http://www.branah.com/chinese-to-pinyin) to convert the characters to pinyin but cannot find a way to do the reverse.

Answer (score 1):

go to [CantroDict --> Search CantroDict](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/scripts/wordsearch.php)

On the pull-down window select search Pinyin (Mandarin)

For example:

Input: zheng4 yi4 (Search: Pinyin)

[Result](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/search/?searchtype=5&text=zheng4%20yi4): 正義 /zheng4 yi4/ justice

or

Go to [CantonesePlus](https://cantoneseplus.com/) --> search words --> input Pinyin:
zheng4 yi4

You will get the same results

Note:

zheng4 yi4 = Zhèng yì (fourth tone). If you start from pinyin with tone-markers, you have to convert it to tone-number for the search above